# Render the same template with different text?

Tags: django

I have about 4-5 templates for my Django project. I want to use each template across about 10 pages(with 10 different sets of content/text) each.

I've been using contexts to fill out the relevant content on each page when it is rendered.

However, I'm not sure about any potential performance loss because the content is quite large. Is there a neat and efficient way to render one template with content relevant to a link clicked on a previous page.

what I'm currently doing:

index.html

```
<div class='well well-sm well-md well-lg'>

<h1> {{variable1}} </h1>

</div>
```

views.py

```
def page1(request):


   variable1 = 'Long text for each variable. Many variables on each page so       
   lots of long text overall. '

   return render(request, 'index/base.html', {'variable': variable1})

def page2(request):


   variable1 = 'More long text. '

   return render(request, 'index/base.html', {'variable': variable1})
```

Basically I want to know if there is a way of doing the above without having to use contexts. Or will I have to create a template for each page?

Comment: Have you looked at [template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance)?

Comment: @JensAstrup hay, yes I've been trying to use it but I can't work out how to extend blocks based on the link clicked on the previous page. I thought it might be some sort of conditional statement but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Check django [tutorial doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial03/)
In url:

```
url(r'^(?P<page_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.page, name='page'),
```

In view:

```
def page(request, page_id):
   // have a dict or list, get result using the page_id
   return render(request, 'index/base.html', {'variable': variable})
```

Or if you don't have a page_id/name system, you can use:

```
def page(request):
    url = request.path
    value = dict[url]
    render (...)
```

Comment: I have a url name system but in order to keep rendering 'index/base.html' with different content the dict's are getting long with lots of text. I'm trying to find a way to do it without having to use context dict's.

Comment: well, you should create model and save them in database

Comment: would that not lead to an unnecessary overhead of having to go to the database every page request? especially for something like some text. I'm being lazy so I don't want to create lots of templates but I'm sure it would probably be more efficient to do that then a db round trip every click.

Answer (score 0):

You need to solve in 2 steps.

1. Determine previous page, so that you choose appropriate text.

You can solve this in the view. Just set some context variable to be passed to templates. I believe this is not easy to do in template processing, view is better.

Sample code

```
def page(request):
   if previous_page == "some page 1"
       page_type = 1
   elif previous_page == "some page 2"
       page_type = 2
   return render(request, 'index/base.html', {'page_type': page_type})
```

2. Then in template use [`{%include%}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#include) tag to use appropriate template.

Sample index.html

```
<div class='well well-sm well-md well-lg'>

{% if page_type == 1 %}
    {%include "page_type1.html"%}
{%else%}
    {%include "page_type2.html"%}
{%endif
</div>
```

You need to write 2 templates `page_type1.html` and `page_type2.html` for render required html.